# addition of not requested code into index.html

Tags: build, bookdown

when executing build book, index.html is gaining "automatic contributions" that I have not ordered; example of the "contribution":

```
   </div>
    <div id="prerequisites" class="section level1">
    <h1><span class="header-section-number"> 1</span> Prerequisites</h1>
    <p>This is a <em>sample</em> book written in <strong>Markdown</strong>. You can use anything that 
    Pandoc’s Markdown supports, e.g., a math equation <span class="math inline">\(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\) 
    </span>
    ...
    </p>class="uri">https://yihui.org/tinytex/</a>.</p>
```

This "gift" is reflected into the ePUB output, but not into the html output

Seems improper to have to edit index.html to exclude this "addition".

Anyone has been able to avoid this effect?

Thank you

Comment: The (markdown) source for this content is included by default in `index.Rmd` when you begin a new bookdown project in RStudio. It's hard to come up with an explanation of why it shows only in ePUB but not HTML output without seeing any code. How does your index.Rmd look?

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr. Xie. When editing the index.Rmd I left only:--- 
title: "Glossário de Termos Técnicos em Avaliação de Tecnologias em Saúde"
author: " Carlos Lederman^3^ e Wanderley Marques Bernardo^4^"
date: "27/10/2020"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
---

Comment: The ePUB comes as: --- 
title: "Glossário de Termos Técnicos em Avaliação de Tecnologias em Saúde"
author: " Carlos Lederman^3^ e Wanderley Marques Bernardo^4^"
date: "27/10/2020"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
---

Comment: Why this "This is a minimal..." is included into the ePUB and not in the HTML (as it would be correct?), as well as "This is a sample book..."? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the ePub is being rebuilt? Could be that it is just an old copy that still has that content.

Comment: Thank you, jbatyly, yes I am sure the book is been rebuilt,